# SharePoint Calculated Column, extract only ONE numerical value

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I've seen the other articles that answer very similar questions but those formulas do not work for me, I needed to post a new question.

I have the following column values:

- Leadership;#4#
- Character;#2#
- Communication;#5#
- Teamwork;#3#

I need to extract ONLY the number from each of those column values. I tried to combine RIGHT & LEFT conditions with no luck. I am on a time crunch and desperate!! Can anyone help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are four separate values and the number is a single digit:

```
Leadership;#4# 
Character;#2# 
Communication;#5# 
Teamwork;#3#
```

You can extract the number using:

```
=LEFT( RIGHT( [TheColumn] ,2) ,1)
```

[image]

If there are many digits then use:

```
=MID(LEFT(TheColumn,LEN(TheColumn)-1), FIND("#",TheColumn)+1,999)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Mike - I took these columns and created a column for the average using =AVERAGE. Do you know how I could avoid getting the #DIV/0 error message? All of my columns have a value in them. I attempted to use ISERROR but no luck.

Comment: Are your Calculated Columns set to return a Number?

Comment: I changed all of the calculated columns to return a number and no luck still. Going to start fresh tomorrow

Comment: Change your Average formula like this:   =AVERAGE( 0 + column1, 0 + column2 )

Comment: That did the trick, thanks again for your help! Do you know why you need to add the zero like that? Curious about the math behind the equation.

Comment: SharePoint columns return text or numbers formatted at text. A pure number might be "1234" while SharePoint coverts it to text, adding commas if needed. I.e. "1,234". (The "," is not a numeric character.) The adding of a number (0) to a column forces the calculation into numeric mode, and a text to number conversion is performed.